# htaccess rule that allows pass of empty query parameter

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I need the following URL structure.

```
https://url.com/info/cars/audi/fastest/1
https://url.com/info/planes/airbus/cheapest/1
```

This is the current .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^info/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /info.php?category=$1&sub_category=$2&sorting=$3&page=$4
```

I need parameters 3 and 4 to be **optional**. Currently, if I leave the page or sub-category empty, it returns a 404 error. But I don't want to pass the page parameter for the first page, for example. That means:

```
https://url.com/info/cars/ <----- this should be equal to sub-category: all, sorting: default, page: 1

https://url.com/info/cars/2 <----- this should be equal to sub-category: all, sorting: default, page: 2
```

I know how to implement in PHP, but that requires that the .htaccess rule is correct. Currently it redirects me to a 404 once I leave one parameter empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have 4 separate rules like this:

```sh
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

# 4 parameters rule
RewriteRule ^info/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ info.php?category=$1&sub_category=$2&sorting=$3&page=$4 [L,QSA,NC]

# 3 parameters rule
RewriteRule ^info/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ info.php?category=$1&sub_category=$2&sorting=$3&page=1 [L,QSA,NC]

# 2 parameters rule 1
RewriteRule ^info/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ info.php?category=$1&sub_category=all&sorting=default&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# 2 parameters rule 2
RewriteRule ^info/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ info.php?category=$1&sub_category=$2&sorting=default&page=1 [L,QSA,NC]

# 1 parameter rule
RewriteRule ^info/([^/]+)/?$ info.php?category=$1&sub_category=all&sorting=default&page=1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: So far so good, but doesn't take it into account `https://url.com/info/cars/2` or `https://url.com/info/cars/audi/2` for example, so that the sorting is optional. Sorry, forgot to put that in intial post!

Comment: Optional parameters should be from end otherwise how would rule know what is missing `sub_category` or `sorting`?